# Wix4 does not install Web application in IIS

Tags: iis, wix, wix4

I had an installer that was working fine in Wix 3.11, recently I tried Wix4. Everything is working fine excepted that the web application is longer installed in IIS. No application pool or website created.

I guess there is something missing that is needed for wix4 but for now the documentation doesn’t seem to indicate that.

I used HeatWave to convert this project.

My component group is referenced in my Feature element.

This is my wxs file containing the IIS configuration:

```
<Wix xmlns=http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs xmlns:iis=http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs/iis>
  <Fragment>
<iis:WebAppPool Id="AspNet4_0" Name="ASP.NET v4.0" />

<DirectoryRef Id="INSTALLFOLDER">
  <Component Id="ApiPool_Comp" Guid="{AFF97B91-D9FF-4CBA-A819-C308800FD392}" KeyPath="yes">
    <iis:WebAppPool Id="ApiPool" 
                                Name="!(loc.ApplicationPoolName)" 
                                ManagedRuntimeVersion="v4.0" 
                                ManagedPipelineMode="integrated" 
                                CpuAction="none" 
                                QueueLimit="1000" 
                                IdleTimeout="0" 
                                Identity="applicationPoolIdentity" 
                                VirtualMemory="0" 
                                MaxWorkerProcesses="1" 
                                RecycleMinutes="1740" 
                                RecycleRequests="0" 
                                PrivateMemory="0"> 
        </iis:WebAppPool>
  </Component>

  <Component Id="ApiWebsite_Comp" Guid="{A9CB9DA6-A3F7-4828-A8CA-B5F0B82CA364}" KeyPath="yes">
    <iis:WebSite Id="ApiSite" AutoStart="yes" StartOnInstall="yes" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER" Description="!(loc.ProductName)">
      <iis:WebAddress Id="ApiWebAddr" IP="*" Port="443" Secure="yes" />
      <iis:WebApplication Id="ApiWebApplication" Name="!(loc.ProductName)" WebAppPool="ApiPool" />
      <iis:WebDirProperties Id="ApiDirProperties" AnonymousAccess="no" BasicAuthentication="no" WindowsAuthentication="yes" />
    </iis:WebSite>
  </Component>
</DirectoryRef>

<ComponentGroup Id="IIS_Api_Configuration">
  <ComponentRef Id="ApiPool_Comp" />
  <ComponentRef Id="ApiWebsite_Comp" />
</ComponentGroup>
  </Fragment>
```

Comment: Which version of Wix v4 are you using? Wix v4 is continuously updated and fix some issues. You can try switching versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bug fixed for the -rc.2 release: https://github.com/wixtoolset/issues/issues/7120

Comment: I installed rc2 build 14 and it still didn't work for me. I'm looking forward to the official rc2 release and will retest.